# Is there an app for that?

Tags: feature-request, stackapps

What I need is simple:

An app, that allows me to track all my questions easily. I find it very hard to keep track of answers at stack overflow, because I am forced to look at my list of questions over and over again just to see if there are new answers for me.

But what I want is an app that notifies me (maybe push notification) about a new answer to an question.

Maybe someone already developed a solution for this?

Comment: all your app are belong to us: http://stackapps.com/?tab=apps

Comment: I'm starting to get allergic reactions to "there is an app for that" references. Strange.

Comment: Why's that strange? It's a totally normal question, and it wasn't "there is an app for that" but "is there an app for that??". Totally different.

Comment: You might try [StackApplet](http://stackapps.com/questions/83/stackapplet-bringing-stack-exchange-notifications-to-your-desktop-1-5-beta-2-r).

Answer (score 2):

Each question has an RSS feed.  Scroll all the way to the bottom right, just above the footer and you'll see the icon.  Each user also has a feed, so you could track all of your activity in an RSS reader with just one subscription.